# mysql: 0 instead of an empty table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause

I have a sql query (simplified example):

```
select 
    ifnull(count(table.id), 0) as count 
from 
    table
where
    table.id > 10000
```

If anything in the table was not found, as a result it displays an empty table, but I want to output 0.

### How can this be done?

my decision (speed has decreased in 5 times!!!)

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS xxx;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE xxx ENGINE = MEMORY AS (SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ...);

IF (FOUND_ROWS() = 0) THEN
    SELECT 0 AS count;
ELSE
    SELECT * FROM xxx;
END IF;
```

### **it's work!** but slowly :(

Sorry, speed is constant :) my mistake

results:
the problem was solved by the use of SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and FOUND_ROWS (thanks @Unknown User)
but temporary tables... not sure about the optimality of such a decision

Comment: Do you have another table where all the `table.ids` exist? Better show us your expected output based on some sample input

Comment: What if instead of `count(table.id)` you try `count(1)`? Also, I don't think you need the `nullif`.

Comment: Build the habit of accepting answers (if it works for you). This is one of the few ways of expressing gratitude in SO.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by not found? Are you for example expecting to find ids between 10000 and 10010 and but want to find if 10009 is missing?

Comment: Why do you `group by table.id`? Without it will return `0`.

Comment: TABLE table:
id: 1,2,3,4,5,..., 10000

count(table.id)... where table.id < 10000 = 9999

count(table.id)... where table.id > 10000 = **no rows, not null, not 0!!!!!!!!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `group by`.  Also, the `ifnull()` is unnecessary:

```
select count(t.id) as `count`
from table t
where t.id > 10000;
```

You seem to want the count of ids that meet the condition.  Your version would return a separate count for each `id`.

If you wanted a separate count for each `id`, you could do:

```
select id, count(t.id) as `count`
from table t
where t.id > 10000
group by id 
union all
select null, 0
from table t
where not exists (select 1 from table t2 where t2.id > 10000);
```

Comment: sorry - 'group by' is my mistake in example (I checked on the example of the work without a 'group by') :)

Comment: @Zhihar . . . You are incorrect.  If there is no group by, the query will return one row, regardless of whether any rows are selected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query. This will give you total # of records with matching query. If there will be no matching results then it will give you `0` .

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows)

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ColumnName FROM TableName WHERE ColumnName IN ('');

SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

Comment: 1000111, COALESCE not work

If the search nothing was found, the number of rows is equal to 0 and COALESCE does not work (empty result without rows, not null result with 1 row)

Comment: @Zhihar You can create a procedure or Use Prepare Statement.

Comment: temporary table (in procedure)?

stage1: select to temporary table
stage2: FOUND_ROWS
stage3: comparison with 0

Comment: ` IF (FOUND_ROWS() = 0) THEN
  SELECT 
   0
 end IF;`

@Unknown User - it's work

Comment: my decision (speed has decreased in 5 times!!!)

    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS xxx;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE xxx ENGINE = MEMORY AS (...);
    
    IF (FOUND_ROWS() = 0) THEN
        SELECT 0 AS count;
    ELSE
        SELECT * FROM xxx;
    END IF; 

**it's work!** but slowly :(

Answer (score 1):

This way:

```
select 
    COALESCE(count(table.id), 0) as count 
from 
    table
where
    table.id > 10000
group by table.id
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use case when for checking no value in table

```
 SELECT case when table.id is null then 0 
 else count(table.id) end as Count_NUM_ID FROM table
  where
 table.id > 10000
```

Comment: Zaynul Abadin Tuhin does not work because...

**0 row(s) returned 0.000 sec / 0.000 sec**

Comment: @Zhihar where you run this sql code in mysql work bench it shows in Action output "17:07:39 SELECT case when time is null then 0   else count(time) end as Count_NUM_ID  FROM test1 1 row(s) returned 0.000 sec / 0.000 sec
"